# Droplist issue in WFFM

Tags: wffm

We are using WFFM (v 2.4) with MVC on Sitecore 8. We have created a form in WFFM which has three fields Name, Email and State. State field is a DropList type field.
The problem which we are facing is that whenever we save the state field values, it is giving values like type name like 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.

I am not sure what is the problem. Can you please suggest the way?

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue and is reported way back in the last year. You may also be getting incorrect values in the message text, when using list field values in the Send Email Message save action if you are using it.

You can get the resolution from https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/311218. Please try to use solution given in this article.